# Electric field per permittivity

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

The magnetic field, $\vec B$, has a close cousin, the auxiliary magnetic field $\vec H$, such that $\vec B = \mu \vec H$, where $\mu$ is the permeability of the environment, measured in henrys per metre (H/m).

This $\vec H$ field has many uses, such as “unambiguously designating the driving magnetic influence from external currents in a material, independent of the material's magnetic response,” according to [*HyperPhysics*](http://HyperPhysics).  The notation also allows for conciseness in stating the Ampère-Maxwell law, $\nabla\times\vec H = \vec J + \left. \partial\vec D \middle/ \partial t\right.$.

Is there any similar field for electric field $\vec E$ that equals $ \left. \vec E \middle/ \varepsilon \right.$ if $\varepsilon$ is the permittivity or the environment through which the electric field propagates, measured in farads per metre (F/m)?

If so, what are the advantages of delineating this field, and what applications could it have as studied by a third-year physics student?

Comment: The E-field *is* analogous to the H-field.

Comment: In what way @RobJeffries ?  Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's an analogous field for electric field. $H$ is an external magnetic field that is on the environment and doesn't depends of any material, and $B$ is the induction that $H$ creates on a specific material with some permeability $\mu$. Because of the external magnetic field the object gets magnetized and we can design it with a new variable $M$. The relationship between $B, M$ and $H$ is:

$B=\mu·(H+M)$

We can relate $M$ with $H$ depending on the character of the material (if it's paramgnetic or ferromagnetic) by $M=\chi·H$, where $\chi$ is the susceptibility of the material.

So we can define $B$ with $H$:

$B=\mu_{0}·\mu_{r}·H=\mu·H$

With electric field is the same, we can define an electric external field as $E$, and it can acts in a material with some electrical susceptibility and it makes that the material gets polarized with $P$.

That variable $P$ depends on $E$ like $P=\chi·E$, so we can define a displacement electrical field $D$ which appears in the Maxwell's equation.

This new field is:

$D=\epsilon_{0}·\epsilon_{r}·E=\epsilon·E$